# Punktion Marks as Chars in C#

Tags: c#, arrays, char

I want to write a Ceaser cypher (de)coder, but I'm stuck at the punctuation marks.
I'm using a char array for the single letters, but punctuation marks don't get copied from the string into the array.

Is there an option to do it in the way I'm trying to use here?

```
static char[] alphabet = new char[]{ 'a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g', 'h', 'i', 'j', 'k', 'l', 'm', 'n', 'o', 'p', 'q', 'r', 's', 't', 'u', 'v', 'w', 'x', 'y', 'z' };

for (int i = 0; i< toEncrypt.Length; i++)
{
        for (int j = 0; j < alphabet.Length; j++ )
        {
            if (toEncrypt[i] == alphabet [j]) 
            {
                encrypted[i] = alphabet [(j + c) % 25];
            }
        }
    }
```

Thanks for your time and sorry for the stupid question :)

Comment: First: Read up on the use of break (to leave a loop when you're really done with it), Dictionary (to create look-up lists), StringBuilder (how to efficiently append to strings)

Answer (score 3):

You need to assign `encrypted[i] = toEncrypt[i];` before your loop

```
static char[] alphabet = new char[]{'a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g', 'h', 'i', 'j', 'k', 'l', 'm', 'n', 'o', 'p', 'q', 'r', 's', 't', 'u', 'v', 'w', 'x', 'y', 'z'
    };

for (int i = 0; i< toEncrypt.Length; i++){
        encrypted[i] = toEncrypt[i]; // first copy the same character, overwrite later if character is in alphabet
        for (int j = 0; j < alphabet.Length; j++ ){
            if (toEncrypt[i] == alphabet [j]) {
                encrypted[i] = alphabet [(j + c)%25];
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: I tried this, and now not even blanks get copied anymore, punctuation marks are still thrown away here.
What is the reason to copy the character first?

Anyway, many thanks for your suggestion!

Comment: The reason is to copy all characters that are not in the alphabet, but you may have done that in a part of your code that you don't show here. I can't try and run your code, since some parts are missing, try to get the code compiling in https://dotnetfiddle.net/ before pasting to make sure you don't miss anything important.